# Excel - Conditional Formatting - Cell not blank and equals 0

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

I'm trying to check if a cell is:

1. blank,  and if false (not blank)
2. If value equals 0. I have tried:

   =IF( NOT( ISBLANK($D:$D) ) & $D:$D=0 ,TRUE,FALSE)

   =IF( AND( NOT( ISBLANK($D:$D) ),$D:$D=0) ,TRUE,FALSE)

I am use **Excel 2013** with *Conditional Formatting* rule: **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** > **Format values where this formula is true**

What am I doing wrong? The problem is, the `IF($D:$D=0)` recognises cells with value **0** and those which are **blank** as *true*. I only want it to recognise 0 values. Not blank.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
=AND(COUNTBLANK($D1)=0,$D1=0)
```

Note that when you apply it to the whole column, each cell will only look at its respective row.  You'll want to keep the reference of $D1 instead of using $D:$D

Comment: You're right. It worked :) Will accept in 3 minutes... Timelimits -.-

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this formula

`=($D1<>"")*($D1=0)`

Answer (score 4):

Before the rule specifying "0" you should add the rule "cell contains empty (blank) value". Then set the format to "no formatting" and then select "stop if true".

Comment: This is probably the easiest way to do it for people who aren't confident with using formulas.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work and you don't  have to worry about how AND and NOT fit together.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),TRUE,IF(A1=0,TRUE,FALSE))
```

Comment: That looks good. Just one more question. I'm setting conditional formatting for the entire Column, so I clicked the Letter D at the top... Hence the `$D:$D` as the cell reference. When I replaced the A1 in your formula with `$D:$D`, it didn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: conditional formatting will auto adjust the cell, use $D1 like @tigeravatar suggested to get the highlighting to work on every column included in your range where the rule applies, or D1 to get just the cell

Answer (score 0):

format only cells that contains -> (Specific text)... Don't use (cell value)-->   then type "0" with no quotation marks

this will format only cells with 0 inside it, blank cells will not be formatted